# How to prevent bucket creation if it is not exists in spark on emr

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, hadoop-partitioning

I'm, running spark step on emr cluster. it gathers all small files and accumulated them to one big file. 
So i receive list of buckets to process, but before processing bucket i want to check if bucket exists and if it contains any files. For that purpose i'm using hadoop FileSystem.

```
     String bucketPath = "s3n://" + bucketName;
     Configuration hadoopConfiguration =   
     sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration();
     FileSystem.get(new URI(bucketPath), hadoopConfiguration);
```

But the issue here that *FileSystem.get(...)* creates a bucket if its not exists.
Is it possible to prevent bucket creation?or does somebody know how to check existence in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to disable this is with the "fs.s3.buckets.create.enabled"  hadoop config.  This feature is going to be disabled in newer versions of emr in the near future to prevent accidentally creating s3 buckets and to improve startup performance.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, your solution works perfect! But i have one more question :) When you wrote about feature will be disabled - did you mean this property will be removed or bucket won't be created by default?

Comment: Its being switch to off by default partially due to the surprise bucket creation and partially due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to disable bucket creation in the IAM role associated to your EMR's JobFlow. BTW it's generally a good idea to adopt [**at least privilege** principle in the security on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege)

An example of IAM policy denying bucket's creation:

```
      {
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Action":[
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:DeleteBucket"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
      },
```

For more information, you can check [Permissions Related to Bucket Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-buckets)