# How to create S3 bucket dynamically in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I would like to "create if not exists" a S3 bucket in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and store my transformed parquet files there. How do you achieve this in pyspark? Should I use boto3 or does pyspark have something builtin?

I am using the code below to read data from S3. I would like to create S3 and put my transformed files there.

```py
spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", config.access_id)

spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", config.access_key)

spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want multiple buckets rather than storing into partitions of one bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to just enable: `fs.s3.buckets.create.enabled`

Comment: What should be the code to create by buckets dynamically?

Comment: Add `set("fs.s3.buckets.create.enabled", "true")` to your spark session, check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078213/how-to-prevent-bucket-creation-if-it-is-not-exists-in-spark-on-emr

Comment: Answer written in 2019... "feature is going to be disabled in newer versions of emr"